# Image from imagestore in listview extremely slow rendering

Tags: android, listview

In my activity I reads out all uri from a database, among ther thigs, then I pass that to a listview, but when I click the "show all" button it take al ot of time to switch to the new activity. Here si some of the code, this is the code to put the picture in the listview.

```
public MyListAdapter() {
        super(ShowAllActivity.this, R.layout.item_list_view, posts);
    }

    /**
     * Get a view for each post in the list.
     * Uses a default picture if there are no photo. If there is a photo for the post then the photo will be correct rotated.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View postView = convertView;
        if (postView == null) {
            postView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_view,
                    parent, false);
        }

        Post currentPost = posts.get(position);
        TextView name = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
        TextView title = (TextView) postView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_item_title);
        TextView date = (TextView) postView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_date);
        ImageView photo = (ImageView) postView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_item_photo);
        name.setText(currentPost.getName());
        title.setText(currentPost.getTitle());
        date.setText(currentPost.getDate());

        Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(currentPost.getPhoto());

        Bitmap myBitmap;

        try {

            Uri selectedImage = photoUri;
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, null,
                    null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            int rotation = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            myBitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    getContentResolver(), photoUri);
            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            mat.postRotate(rotation);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap;
            int scaleFactor = 20;
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap
                    .createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, myBitmap.getWidth()/scaleFactor, myBitmap.getHeight()/scaleFactor, true);
            Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), mat,
                    true);
            photo.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        return postView;
    }
}
```

Comment: May be you are working on your Main Thread.

Comment: Remember Bitmaps are heavy resources, so accessing them may take time. Are you using ViewHolder in the getView() method of your Adapter? Post that as well?

Comment: Updated with more code